# Symfony/Doctrine - createQueryBuilder orderBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I have a 'Team' Entity with a property 'budget'. I just want to print the teams properties and i want that the team with the biggest budget appear in first position, the second, the third... (DESC).

But with this code, it does not work and i don't understand why.

**indexAction** (controller)

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $teams = $em->getRepository('FootballBundle:Team')->getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget();


    return $this->render('FootballBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'teams' => $teams,
    ));
```

**TeamRepository**

```
public function getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget()
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $q->select()->from('FootballBundle:Team', 't')->orderBy('t.budget', 'DESC');

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**twig view**

```
<h1>Teams list</h1>
<ul>
    {% for team in teams  %}
        <li>{{ team.name }} - {{ team.championship }} - {{ team.budget|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}£</li>
    {% endfor  %}
    <br/>
</ul>
```

**Team.php** entity

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="budget", type="integer")
 */
private $budget;
```

And here, the result ...

```
Teams list

Manchester City FC - Premier League - 100,000,000.00£
Arsenal FC - Premier League - 50,000,000.00£
Leicester City - Premier League - 20,000,000.00£
Crystal Palace FC - Premier League - 5,000,000.00£
Chelsea FC - Premier League - 100,000,000.00£
```

Chelsea... lol

**EDIT** : CORRECTED ! See the *takeit* comment.

Comment: how your `budget` property and the mapping look like in your entity?

Comment: /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="budget", type="integer")
     */
    private $budget;

Comment: first of all try: `public function getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget()
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')->orderBy('t.budget', 'DESC');

        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }`

Comment: maybe the `number_format(2, '.', ',')` twig filter causes this issue on your `budget` value? what if you remove it ? what results are you getting ?

Comment: Why not use the second array on `findBy()` to order the results? `$teams = $em->getRepository('FootballBundle:Team')->findBy(array(), array('budget' => 'DESC'));`

Comment: @IbaduLLAH does it work ?

Comment: @takeit Yes, but i don't now how to close the post

Comment: @IbaduLLAH If it works then please accept my answer. Good that it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your `QueryBuilder` query in `getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget` method to:

```
public function getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget() 
{ 
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->orderBy('t.budget', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the sort() to perfrom the ordering.

```
public function getAllTeamsSortedByDescBudget() { 
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
       ->sort('t.budget', 'DESC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); 
}
```